# Having trouble displaying Folder chosen using PySimpleGUI

Tags: pysimplegui

I am working on creating a GUI for testing. But I want to display the directory that the user chose. I want it to be displayed on top of the button they pressed. The relevant part is right next to FolderBrowse. I have tried putting in sgText() but it is not showing the user selected directory. I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and no luck.

Here is the code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import logging
sg.theme('SandyBeach')

logger = logging.getLogger('chere')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

ch.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(ch)

layout = [[sg.Text('How many driver bits do you need? (Enter a number between 1 and 15)'), ],
          [sg.Input('')],
          [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
          [sg.Button('Next >'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window1 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout, element_justification='c')

window4_active = window5_active = window6_active = window3_active = window2_active = window4_active = False

while True:
    if not window2_active:
        event1, values1 = window1.read()
        if event1 is None or event1 == 'Exit':
            break
        window1['-OUTPUT-'].update(values1[0])

    if not window2_active and event1 == 'Next >':
        window2_active = True
        window1.hide()
        layout2 = [[sg.Text('How many bytes are needed? (Enter a number between 1 and 15)')],
                   [sg.Input('')],
                   [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
                   [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]

        window2 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout2, element_justification='c')

    if window2_active:
        event2 = window2.read()[0]
        if event2 in (None, 'Exit', '< Prev'):
            window2_active = False
            window2.close()
            window1.un_hide()
        elif event2 == 'Next >':
            window3_active = True
            window2_active = False
            window2.hide()
            layout3 = [[sg.Text('Choose .CSV/Excel File')],
                       [sg.FileBrowse(sg.Text())],
                       [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
                       [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]
            window3 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout3, element_justification='c')

    if window3_active:
        event3, values3 = window3.read()
        if event3 == '< Prev':
            window3.close()
            window3_active = False
            window2_active = True
            window2.un_hide()
        elif event3 == 'Next >':
            window4_active = True
            window3_active = False
            window3.hide()
            layout4 = [[sg.Text('Please choose where you would like to export the .BIN files...')],
                       [sg.FolderBrowse(sg.Text())],
                       [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
                       [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]
            window4 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout4, element_justification='c')

    if window4_active:
        event4, values4 = window4.read()
        if event4 == '< Prev':
            window4.close()
            window4_active = False
            window3_active = True
            window3.un_hide()
        elif event4 == 'Next >':
            window5_active = True
            window4_active = False
            window4.hide()
            layout5 = [[sg.Text('Please confirm if your chosen settings are correct')],
                       [sg.Input('')],
                       [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
                       [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]
            window5 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout5, element_justification='c')
            

    if window5_active:
        event5, values5 = window5.read()
        if event5 == '< Prev':
            window5.close()
            window5_active = False
            window4_active = True
            window4.un_hide()
        elif event5 == 'Next >':
              window6_active = True
              window5_active = False
              window5.hide()
              layout6 = [[sg.Text('Compilation Complete! \nYour files have been saved in your chosen directory.')],
                         [sg.Button('Finish!')]]
              window6 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout6, element_justification='c')
              
    if window6_active:
         event6, values6 = window6.read()
         if event6 == 'Finish!':
             window6.close()
             break                         
window1.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`[sg.FileBrowse(sg.Text())]` wrong statement in your layout.

It maybe in one of following way

```py
layout = [[sg.Text(''), sg.FileBrowse()]]                               # Target is the left one (sg.ThisRow, -1)
layout = [[sg.FileBrowse(target=(sg.ThisRow, 1)), sg.Text('')]]         # Target is the right one
layout = [[sg.Input(key='-INPUT-')], [sg.FileBrowse(target='-INPUT-')]] # Target with key '-INPUT-'
layout = [[sg.FileBrowse(target='-INPUT-')], [sg.Input(key='-INPUT-')]] # Target with key '-INPUT-'
```